# When using mulesoft proxy does it set the X-Forwarded-For IP of the client making the request?

Tags: api, mulesoft

We are using mulesoft proxy api as proxy for another api. We need to know the X-Forwarded-For of the originating requestor.

Comment: Is it an autogenerated proxy? To which version of Mule is it deployed?

Comment: And where is it deployed? CloudHub, RTF, standalone Mule server? is the client sending the X-Forwarded-For header or do you want the proxy to create it?

Comment: Is running on mulesoft server. Want mulesoft proxy to add the X-Forwarded-For. The proxy is setup on the anypoint portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the proxy with API Manager you could add a [Header Injection policy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/header-injection-policy) to it to add the header. You could use as the value the expression #[attributes.remoteAddress] so it takes the IP of the client of the IP.

If the proxy is deployed to CloudHub it might be receiving the IP of CloudHub load balancer and the load balancer may be already adding the X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: By adding this policy it will add the X-Forwarded-For into the header that is passed through the proxy?

Comment: Where do you find a list of these header attributes #[attributes.xxx] ?

Comment: If the header is received by the proxy from a load balancer then it should forward it. You can add the header in case it is not received by the proxy. The attributes from the Mule HTTP connector are in the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-documentation#HttpRequestAttributes

Comment: I don't see reference to the attributes.remoteAddress on that reference page. There is http.remote.address.

Comment: Unfortunately the table uses human readable names instead of the identifiers used in expressions ("Remote Address"). "Former http.remote.address" that is what is called in Mule 3, that's the reason it is called 'former'. If you see the migration guide you will see that it is the right equivalent: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/migration-connectors-http#attributes